# Angular 8: Getting this error 'Cannot POST signup'

Tags: angular

I'm working on an assignment, but I am stuck with a few errors. First of all it is the signup, which prints this error shown on the image. I'm not sure where exactly this error is refering me to look. It keeps running a 'circle' showing that it is busy creating, but it goes on and nothing happens.

What does this error say and how can I solve it please?

This is the signup service.

```
 // Sign up service
  SignUp(data: SignupDto) {
    const API_URL = `${environment.apiEndPoint}/signup`;
    const object = JSON.stringify(data);

    return this.http.post(API_URL, object, { headers: this.headers, responseType: 'text' });
  }
```

This is the environment.ts file

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  apiEndPoint: 'http://localhost:4200/'
};
```

This is the app-routing-module.ts file

```
import { NgModule, Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { CreateWorkoutComponent } from './components/create-workout/create-workout.component';
import { EditWorkoutComponent } from './components/edit-workout/edit-workout.component';
import { WorkoutOverviewComponent } from './components/workout-overview/workout-overview.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import { SignupComponent} from './components/signup/signup.component'
import { AuthGuard } from './helpers/authGuard';


const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'CreateWorkoutComponent', component: CreateWorkoutComponent, canActivate:[AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'EditWorkout', component: EditWorkoutComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
  { path: 'workoutOverview', component: WorkoutOverviewComponent, canActivate:[AuthGuard]},
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'signup', component: SignupComponent},
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'login' },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
  // constructor(private router: Router) {
  //   this.router.errorHandler = (error: any) => {
  //       this.router.navigate(['404']); // or redirect to default route
  //   }
  // }
}
```

This is the console output, when I try to signup.
[image]

I also have another error above the signup error, which I also have no clue what goes wrong there. I'm not sure if these two error are related?

I want to solve one error and then move to the next one. If it is not irrelevant, I would like to ask for help with both of these two errors.
[image]

Comment: Stackblitz required here, also paste the code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You are Getting this error 'Cannot POST signup' because the signup is seems to be some backend service that you are using to post the form data to save it.

Please insure you are using the proper port number not the proper url for the signup service

Say as a sample like below

```
localhost:8090/signup
```

This is the app-routing-module.ts file

```
import { NgModule, Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { CreateWorkoutComponent } from './components/create-workout/create-workout.component';
import { EditWorkoutComponent } from './components/edit-workout/edit-workout.component';
import { WorkoutOverviewComponent } from './components/workout-overview/workout-overview.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import { SignupComponent} from './components/signup/signup.component'
import { AuthGuard } from './helpers/authGuard';


const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'CreateWorkoutComponent', component: CreateWorkoutComponent, canActivate:[AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'EditWorkout', component: EditWorkoutComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
  { path: 'workoutOverview', component: WorkoutOverviewComponent, canActivate:[AuthGuard]},
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'signup', component: SignupComponent},
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'login' },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
  // constructor(private router: Router) {
  //   this.router.errorHandler = (error: any) => {
  //       this.router.navigate(['404']); // or redirect to default route
  //   }
  // }
}
```

For second image the "create-workout" is the route you are assessing in the url which is not found so that is why it is throwing an error.  Try to add the create-workout route in route.config file and add the route the config file in the app.modules to be loaded in to the angular app

Or if added previously then match the url with the path you have specified in the path key for that component

Answer Update 1

The routing path for create-work is specified wrong in the url for accessing.

Use the `CreateWorkoutComponent` instead of create-workout in the url it will work properly

Update 2 
For the api purpose the api url in environment is set to the localhost:4200/ which is the same as the  project where the angular is running please provide the path of the back end url with proper port number there don't set it to the current path of the angular development

Comment: Thanks. This localhost:8090/signup doesn't run either. As for the routing part, I have app-routing.module.ts file containing all the routings, which is also imported in app.module.ts.

Comment: I added the signup service. Can you see if this is the problem?

Comment: What's the value in ${environment.apiEndPoint}

Comment: It seems to be empty or "" so that's why your api is hitting the same host

Comment: updated the code. Added the environment.ts and routing file